# How to use Apache calcite LIKE_REGEX

Tags: regex, apache-calcite

I would like to use LIKE_REGEX in Apache calcite SQL query and can not find any documentation or examples on how to use it. Can you please share examples or documentation around it's usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE_REGEX` was introduced in the SQL:2008 standard but as of version 1.17 Calcite does not currently support it. (If you look at Calcite's SQL reference, `LIKE_REGEX` appears in [Calcite's list of reserved SQL keywords](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#keywords) because Calcite automatically reserves keywords listed in the SQL standard.)

If you would like to match regular expressions, use `SIMILAR TO`. For example, the query `VALUES 'abcccd' similar to 'ab*c+d'` returns `TRUE`.

Calcite's implementation of `SIMILAR TO` has semantics similar to [PostgreSQL's implementation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: Thanks Julian. Your suggestion worked. Since it was on reserved list, I was under the impression it was implemented.